# How to consume an MIME response attachment in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, jasperserver

I am working with a java-written web service called JasperServer. I would like to obtain a file from the web service and save it on my local.

---

The web service provides a get() method; it requests a String of XML, and returns a String, and the target file as a MIME attachment:

```
public string get(string requestXmlString)
```

Right now I try to use a string to take in the response:

```
String res2 = webServiceClient.get(xmlInput);
```

---

It gives me an Exception:

> Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<7817FB68F69B037F5A5DEDE2AC105A65>";    boundary="----=_Part_2_1089980294.1393857885100"', but expected 'text/xml'.

The request failed with the error message:

```
------=_Part_2_1089980294.1393857885100
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <7817FB68F69B037F5A5DEDE2AC105A65>
```

---

So my question is how to consume an String response with MIME attachment in C# .Net. And how to save it to my local?

Comment: Thanks nandhp for editing my post. This is my first post on Stack, my format is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a component for parsing MIME format described by RFC 822/2045 and extensions. 
.NET framework doesn't include built-in classes for that.

I've good experience with [Mime4Net](http://www.mime4.net/) component (it is based on port from Apache mime4j):

```
Stream mimeMsgStream;
var m = new MimeMessage(mimeMsgStream);
```

MimeMessage provides DOM for MIME structure and attachment content could be easily extracted. Also note that Mime4Net is free only for non-commercial usage.

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy! 
But free only for non-commercial usage is not working for me. Like what you said, .Net doesn't have a built-in class for that and I found Jasperserver doesn't support SOAP well. So I use REST instead SOAP, the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with consuming Java WS. 
On WCF3 config I only add the messageEncoding propery to binding definition and set it to "Mtom".
Something like this:

```
...
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="e3" messageEncoding="Mtom">
```